# pynput keyboard typing upper case letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, keyboard, pynput

I'm facing a weird issue here with the pynput library and maybe one of you might enlighten me.

So this is a simple code that will help you to reproduce the behavior I'm having.

install pynput `pip install pynput` then copy and paste the code into a .py file and run it. Then in a notepad try to hit the "ENTER" key and then "; the" key

They both call the execute_command method, but one prints everything correctly and the other one everything or almost everything in upper case.

[image: result]

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener

class KeyListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listener = Listener(on_press=self.on_press)
        self.listener.start()
        self.keyboard = Controller()

    def on_press(self, key):
        try:
            if key == Key.esc:
                self.stop()
            elif key == Key.enter or key.char == ";":
                # Execute the command when "Enter" or ";" is detected
                self.execute_command()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def execute_command(self):
        # just print something
        self.keyboard.type('Test from the execute command')

    def stop(self):
        self.listener.stop()

def main():   
    listener = KeyListener()
    listener.listener.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I appreciate your help.

FYI: I'm currently using a (german) qwertz keyboard

Comment: On the English-Russian keyboard, it prints this way and that in lower case.

Comment: It turns out the code `";"` is the same as the `shift key`.

Comment: @СергейКох it turns out that I have the same behavior with ":" or "/" so I'm not so sure that it's the same as shift key, but for sure it has to do something with shift key because if you change the key to be like 'z' it's not doing it any more